# Is this usage correct? "Please get your parents to come tonight"

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, bare-infinitive

Are all of these correct?

> Please get your parents to come tonight.
>
> Please have your parents to come tonight.
>
> Please ask your parents to come tonight.

And which is most suitable to sound more pressing and urge that person?

Comment: I think all three are correct with the first in the title being the strongest.

Comment: The first sentence in the actual post is not correct.

Comment: Thanks @DanD. The person told me this is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to strengthen the request,then **encourage** is a perfectly acceptable word.

> Please encourage your parents to come tonight.

While there appears to be a consensus that *get your parents to* is "correct", I cannot avoid the feeling that it is at least inelegant. Although you might say it in conversation, I would avoid the expression in writing.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence in the title is correct, as is your last suggestion, but the first sentence is not. It should be:

> Please have your parents come tonight.

If you want to make it an urgent plea, you can build that into the sentence with something like:

> Please urge your parents to come tonight.

Comment: I will consider and mark this answer correct, unless someone objects.  Thanks @ElendilTheTall

Answer (score 2):

The most formal and appropriate to a wide range of situations is the third in the list. This would be appropriate for a teacher to say to a student for example.

Number one is correct but quite colloquial (as are many phrases with "get"). More likely to be used between peers: Get Mark to call me when he's home.

The second phrase is grammatically incorrect. It should be: Please have your parents come tonight. But it is unlikely to be used in this context as the person carrying the message (the child/student) doesn't have the authority to do so, or it is simply inappropriate. In a business setting, leaving a message with a sectretary "please have Mr. X call me as soon as possible" is appropriate and common.